# Integrating SQLAlchemy's ORM with existing classes in pylons

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, pylons

I have a class in my existing python project, User, that I would like to map to tables.  But I'm not sure what the best way to do this is?

Does this mean I can remove:

```
class User:
    pass
```

from my model/__ init __.py?

Or should I leave that in there, and have something like:

```
from project.model.user import User
class User:
    pass
```

In essence, having (2) different classes with the same name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define a class that maps onto a table in the model's __init__.py file, nor should you have two different clases with the same name.

Classes that map onto tables belong in your project's model directory, grouped into modules.  Then import the classes in __init__.py to make them available.